# Regarding translation invariance (equivariance) property of risk measure

Tags: measure-theory, optimization, lebesgue-measure, operations-research, invariance

While studying some literatures for stochastic programming and risk averse optimization, I read that risk measure is called as coherent, when it satisfies:

1. Convexity
2. Monotonicity
3. TRANSLATIONAL INVARIANCE
4. Positive homogeneity.

To point out my question regarding 3., let $\rho[]$ be a risk measure. We say that $\rho[]$ is translational invariant, if for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $\rho[Z+a] = \rho[Z] + a$.

However, if we remember the definition of translational invariance of measure theory, let $\lambda$ be Lebesgue measure defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, given a set $I$ (let $I = (c,d) \in \mathcal{F(\mathbb{R}})$, if we define $I+a = [c,d] + a = [a+c, d+c]$, we have $\lambda(I) = \lambda(I+a) = d-c$, which makes Lebesgue measure translation invariant.

In this regard, clearly the definition of translational invariance for risk measure is, indeed, TRANSLATIONAL VARIANCE. Since this variation is linear (quantifiable given input), we might want to call it as Translational EQUIVARIANT, but not invariant. Am I wrong here...?

I don't get why the name translation invariance appears in risk measure literatures...

Anybody has answer to this question?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_measure#Mathematically wikipedia lists the property as “translative” and writes $\rho(Z+a)=\rho(Z)-a$

Comment: Additionally, “deviation risk measures” have translational invariance $D(X+a)=D(X)$, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviation_risk_measure

Comment: Can you include which books or literature seem to have this inconsistency?

Comment: @NapD.Lover Unfortunately, at the same wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_risk_measure

Comment: They say translative for risk measure, and translation invariant for coherent risk measure...

Comment: It’s quite the unfortunate name choice (for coherent risk) indeed. Cash additivity or something along those lines, as the answer below suggests, seems more appropriate.

Comment: @NapD.Lover Totally agree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite right as stated. We think of adding $a$ as adding cash to the portfolio. It seems to me that most commonly this property is called *cash-additivity*. This stipulates risk reduction by the amount of cash thrown into the portfolio ($\rho(Z+a) = \rho(Z)-a$).

I agree that the name *translation invariance* is unfortunate in this context.

Comment: I got it. Thanks :)